# Dynamically creating JavaScript function which will hide and display the div in JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

My JSP code is

```
<c:forEach var="batchException" items="${batchExceptionType}">
<button> ${batchException.key}</button>
<div id="${batchException.key}">
...
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

batchExceptionType is a Map which is coming from Java Code using JSTL.

I want to hide and display the div on the button click.

As number of div created is not fixed. So I am not sure how to create JavaScript functions to hide and display this div

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which div you want to hide or show?

Comment: <div id="${batchException.key}"></div> . This div

Comment: try to review my answer may be it can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<c:forEach var="batchException" items="${batchExceptionType}">
<button onclick="hideShowDiv(${batchException.key})"> ${batchException.key}</button>
<div id="${batchException.key}">
...
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

and then in script

```
<script>
   function hideShowDiv(divId){
      $(#divId).toggle();
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it also with a pure CSS solution.
by using an input checkbox and it's style property `:checked`.

```
<label class="button" for="toggle-1">${batchException.key}</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div id="${batchException.key}">
```

and CSS:

```
div {
       display: none
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {
       display: inherit;
}
```

better explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

Comment: thanks for your time . I dont want to change my CSS  :)

Comment: fair enough. you asked for a JS solution... but the other answer is also doing jQuery...